# How to find the composition of case-defined functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let 
$$g(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        3+x & \text{if $x\leq0$} \\
        3-x &\text{if $x > 0$}
    \end{cases}$$

Find $f$ if $f$ is defined as $f(x) = g(g(x))$. How to solve the problem analytically? I can calculate specific values of $f$, but don't know how to obtain a general formula for it.

Comment: Try calculating. What is $g(1)$? What is $g(g(1))$? What is $g(-1)$? What is $g(g(-1))$?

Comment: @uniquesolution I tried. I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: There, someone did it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$f(x) = g(g(x)) = \begin{cases}
3+g(x) & \text{if }g(x) \leq 0\\
3-g(x) & \text{if }g(x) > 0
\end{cases}$$
Now $g(x) \leq 0$, when $x \leq -3$ or $x \geq 3$ and $g(x) > 0$ when $x \in (-3,3)$.
Hence,
$$f(x) = g(g(x)) = \begin{cases}
3+(3+x) = x+6&  x \leq -3\\
3-(3+x) = -x & x \in (-3,0]\\
3- (3-x) = x& x \in (0,3)\\
3+(3-x) = -x+6& x \geq 3
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x)=3-|x|$$
so 
$$g(g(x))=3-|3-|x||$$